# How to get bundle product ID by its child id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

Hi I am trying to get the bundle product ID by its child id in Magento 2 but I cant
for config and grouped product I use

```
$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());

$groupParentId = $objectManager->create('Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());
```

**how can I get the same for the bundled products?**

Answer (score 0):

after searching so much I found the answer and that is

```
$bundledParentId = $objectManager->create('Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type')->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());
```

through this, I get bundle productId by its child Id.